# How do I create a label for a custom Orbeon control

Tags: orbeon, xbl

The label is missing the "for" attribute on my custom control. I was using lhha mode, but have now switched to custom-lhha mode to try to correct the issue.

The code below is doing something very odd. The label element contains two nested spans with the correct label content and the for attribute contains a partial of the correct id.

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
     xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">

<xbl:binding element="fr|image-picker" id="fr-image-picker" xxbl:mode="lhha custom-lhha binding value" xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">
    <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
        <display-name lang="en">Image Picker</display-name>
        <icon lang="en">
            <small-icon>/apps/fr/assets/img/camera.png</small-icon>
            <large-icon>/apps/fr/assets/img/camera.png</large-icon>
        </icon>
        <templates>
            <view>
                <fr:image-picker id="image-picker" ref="">
                    <xf:label ref=""/>
                    <xf:hint ref=""/>
                    <xf:help ref=""/>
                    <xf:alert ref=""/>
                </fr:image-picker>
            </view>
        </templates>
    </metadata>
    <xbl:template>
        <xh:label for=""><xf:output value="xxf:label('fr-image-picker')"/></xh:label>
        <xf:input ref="xxf:binding('fr-image-picker')" class="image-picker"/>
    </xbl:template>
</xbl:binding>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. You want to place the label *within* the XBL template?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm just trying things to get it to work. When I don't have the label in there it doesn't have a for attribute. When I add it in the template it has half of the id.

Comment: I don't think I can answer your question if you don't tell me what you are trying to do ;) What about you provide an example how *how* you want to use that component?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that defines a simple component with a binding and label support. When I *use* the component, I simply use a regular `xf:label`:

```
<xh:html
        xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
    <xh:head>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance>
                <form xmlns=""/>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
        <xbl:xbl xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">
            <xbl:binding element="fr|image-picker" id="fr-image-picker" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value" xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">
                <xbl:template>
                    <xf:input ref="xxf:binding('fr-image-picker')"/>
                </xbl:template>
            </xbl:binding>
        </xbl:xbl>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:image-picker ref=".">
            <xf:label>My Label</xf:label>
        </fr:image-picker>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

If you want to use an external label with `for`, simply give an id to `fr:image-picke` and use `for` as usual:

```
<xf:label for="my-date-picker">My Label</xf:label>
<fr:image-picker id="my-date-picker" ref="."/>
```